# Undefined reference for image

Tags: graphics, errors, undefined, acmart

I am using the classic 2-columns acmart template, also available on overleaf. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        \includegraphics{myimg.png}%
    }
    \caption{mycaption} 
    \label{polls}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I am getting the error

```
Reference 'polls' on page 3 undefined
```

I have already inserted other images in the documents this way, so there are other columns-sized images in the document, I am getting this error really out of the blue. If I do instead

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \includegraphics{myimg.png}%
        }
        \caption{mycaption} 
        \label{polls}
    \end{figure*}
```

the image appears but, given the presence of `*`, it is located in the following page, in the center. I would like it to be framed within the column instead, like all the other figures. The issue remains if I change input file or caption or whatever.

How could I sort this out?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which _reproduces the issue_. Right now we can only guess. Unrelated: the correct way to rescale an image is through the optional parameter: `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{...}`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: at the first run of LaTeX you get the warning, which is expected; not at the next run.

Comment: the posted code can not produce the warning that you show `Reference 'polls' on page 3 undefined`  please edit the example to use `example-image.png` a test file that is available for these tests, and that produces an undefined reference warning on the second run of latex.